# How to get all data before and after 10 days of interval?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.6

```
    SELECT * FROM events  WHERE `date` 
    BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD
    (NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) order by date
```

I am using the above code to extract the events data of ten days of interval. Now I want to Extract out all the data before this 10 days of interval and after 10 days of interval. How can I do that in a perfect way?

Please help. Advance thanks for your time

Comment: What do you mean?  10-20 days ago?  10-20 days into the future?  20-30, etc?

Comment: I want both. Once I have to show past data and then I have show future data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably best to issue two queries.

```
SELECT * FROM events
    WHERE `date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
      AND `date`  < NOW();

SELECT * FROM events
    WHERE `date` >= NOW()
      AND `date`  < NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

You could get both at once, but it could be inconvenient if you need to separate them:

```
SELECT * FROM events
    WHERE `date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
      AND `date`  < NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

If you want to base on midnight instead of the current second, use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()`.